# Remove ip address in a text file and replace it with the random ip address in python

Tags: python

```py
import fileinput
import re
for line in fileinput.input('./log'):
    ips = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line.rstrip())
    for ip in ips:
        re.sub(ip,'0.0.0.0',line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

I tried this  to replace ip address ith 0.0.0.0 but it dint work

Comment: It is recommended to show your attempts and any errors you are getting when asking a question. This enables us to help better and faster. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidelines.

Comment: import fileinput
import re
for line in fileinput.input('./log'):
    ips = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line.rstrip())
    for ip in ips:
        re.sub(ip,'0.0.0.0',line.rstrip())
    print(line)

Comment: Are you trying to answer your question? If so, please post a separate answer. [Comments are not the correct place for it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

So I have tested the above with a mixture of some other suggestions and the below finally worked for me

```
import fileinput
import re
from random import randint

filename = '/path/to/some/dir/syslog_.log'

for line in fileinput.input(filename):
    ips = re.findall(r'src=[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', line.rstrip())
    print(ips)
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True,backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            try:
                rand_ip = 'src=' + '%d.%d.%d.%d' % (randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255))
                print(line.replace(ips[0], rand_ip), end='')
            except Exception as e:
                raise
            else:
                pass
            finally:
                pass
```

The original file is cleared completely but a .bak file is created with all the original data + the new generated IP's. also the try except is just a template that needs to be filled but this is working with large files - I have tested with 2G file.

Answer (score -1):

```py
f = open('filename.txt','w')
from random import randint
# Ugly part:
str = '%d.%d.%d.%d' % (randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255),randint(0,255))
f.write(str)
f.close()
```

Comment: This just writes one ip to a file, doesn't do what he asked for.

Comment: @Pablo I do not think an answer needs to be fully complete. It answers the thrust of the question. It shows how to generate a random IP. It is the responsibility of the asker to adapt it for their problem.

Comment: But this is misleading. The question is to replace some values. Which basically means, (1) going through a file, (2) finding matches to IPs and (3) replacing those for randomly generated ones.

This reply opens a file, generates a random IP and writes it to the file. All this, while not explaining what their code is doing?